# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'xxx' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in xxx on line 147

Tags: php

I have in a page, a submit button for updating data.
After update, before redirect (using header) I put a 
"`require_once()`" 
and it throws me this error.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6OhP.png)

I must tell you that on the top of php I also use `require_once()` for the database connection and that one doesn't give me any error.
Also if I run only the included page it does its job (sending notification e-mail).

Error message is:

> Warning: require_once(../_mail/mail_utilizator.php?user_id=1&user_edit=2): failed to open stream: No error in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rebat_PlantObjectives_admin\admin_cp_settings_utilizatori.php on line 147
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../_mail/mail_utilizator.php?user_id=1&user_edit=2' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rebat_PlantObjectives_admin\admin_cp_settings_utilizatori.php on line 147"

My code:

```
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $rebat_plantobjectives) or die(mysql_error()); 
$user_id=$_SESSION['MM_UtilizatorID']; 
require('../mail/mail_utilizator.php?user_id='.$user_id.'&user_edit='.$last_id); 
$insertGoTo = "admin_cp_settings_utilizatori.php"; 
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) { 
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?"; $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 
} 
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo)); }
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you show code, where are these errors?

Comment: Of course. I use Dreamweaver so please do not blame me: is the only way I can understand something :) Code is here:
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $rebat_plantobjectives) or die(mysql_error());
$user_id=$_SESSION['MM_UtilizatorID'];
require('../mail/mail_utilizator.php?user_id='.$user_id.'&user_edit='.$last_id);
$insertGoTo = "admin_cp_settings_utilizatori.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

Comment: @Normis If you want, I can show you more of the code, by doing a printscreen

Comment: @BalajOvidiu NO screenshots please. You can edit **your own question** adding code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't define the GET parameters via adding ?xx=yy to an include (require) statement.

If you include a file all the variables from the parent file are also available in the included child file.

You can do:
(If you have to set the GET values)

```
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $rebat_plantobjectives) or die(mysql_error()); 
$user_id=$_SESSION['MM_UtilizatorID']; 
$_GET['user_id'] =$user_id;
$_GET['user_edit'] =$last_id;
require( __DIR__.'/../mail/mail_utilizator.php'); 
$insertGoTo = "admin_cp_settings_utilizatori.php"; 
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) { 
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?"; $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 
} 
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo)); }
```

Or better just use `$last_id` and `$user_id` in the included  `mail_utilizator.php` file.

Comment: Mate, you were right!
I simply got out the parameters and used session variables, and now it works just fine!
Thank you from the bottom of my heart!

Good luck further!

Comment: Of course!
I just have to find out from where do I do that :)

Comment: I am new here. I put the 'accepted' answer but when I try to press "This answer is useful" it sais that I need 15 reputation :)